# Can somebody explain to me thoroughly about DDRx, PORTx, PINx in AVR?

Tags: avr

Okay this might be a really dumb question, but I don't really get these 3,
my main confusion is, why we need three of them? Why can't we r/w on port like normal register? (please don't downvote).
And also from searching around the web, someone mentions about pullups resistor, and now I'm super confused...

Comment: Have you attempted to read the datasheet?

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf Chapter 11

Comment: okay let me try :').

Comment: There is tons of information about AVR programming and basics available online, did you try reading some of that first?

Comment: yeah I did, but I'm quite confused, my pre-knowledge wasn't enough actually.. 
came from math backgrounds and now I gotta learn this in CS :').

Comment: can someone explain, why the ports must be interfaced with three register? why can't we just r/w to the port like normal register? tried reading the datasheets, and still confused

Comment: I will explain my confusion further, why can't a port have only 1 interfacing register where we can read/write from there ? I don't understand the purpose of having those 3.

Comment: You need 3 registers because they store 3 (mostly) uncorrelated data: what we want on pin(PORT), what is on pin (PIN) and data direction (DDR)

Comment: umm .. still don't get it, why can't that three be put on a single register ? a register that have what is on pin. and if we write to it, we change it to what we want on pin... I really don't get it. 

isn't changing the pin(PORT) changing the pin(PIN) also ? I'm very confused now.. @Rokta

Comment: Because you can change what is on pin by driving it with mcu or by applying external voltage on pin. But that isnt whole story for this mcu as these 3 registers have few more function as described in vicatcus answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They chose to group he control bits in registers by function. They only need three control bits per pin. Using one register per pin is wasteful, and with 8 pins per port,  you would need 24 bits of control state, which is 3 registers worth, anyway. They cram that into two registers by contextualizing the meaning of PORT bits. Grouping it differently could also make for some ugly low- level software.

The bits directly support the data path for an I/O pin. The DDR is the data direction register.

If a DDR bit is high,  the pin is configured as an output, and the value of the corresponding PORT bit sets the value of the pin HIGH or LOW.

If a DDR bit is low, the pin is configured as an input, and if the corresponding PORT bit is set, an internal pull-up resistor is enabled,  otherwise the pin is floating subject to external circuits. In any case,  the corresponding PIN bit reflects the logic state of the pin, HIGH or LOW.

If you read enough avr-gcc code,  you see a lot of use if the _BV macro to construct bit masks, which can be a useful way to manipulate an entire 8-bit port with of state in one instruction for parallel functionality.

***Update to request for clarification***
For each pin,  you have to encode the following control state in AVR8 architecture.

- whether the pin is configured as input or output
- for input,  whether the internal pull-up resistor is enabled or not.
- for output, what value should be driven to the pin
- for input, what binary value is on the pin

There is no way to encode all that information in one bit per pin. They already compress some of that state by contextualizing the meaning of ther PORT bits based on corresponding DDR bits.

Could it be encoded differently? Sure, but the architecture is what it is in hardware. You have to look at the I/O pin block diagram in the datasheet to fully understand. Doing so,  it should be clear how these control bits for each pin influence the datapath.

PIN bits are not really a control bits. Together,  three control states are encoded by two bits per pin between DDR and PORT registers.

Comment: not one register per pin, but one register for 8 pins, can you explain it to me more thoroughly (the confusing part is the first paragraph only)

Comment: I mean one register (first bit is for reading/writing to the first pin, and so on), I don't get it sir, very sorry :(.

Comment: umm, why should a pin be configured as input/output before using sir? can't I set/get data from it directly ?

Comment: so what are PIN bits ? isn't it 8 bits too ?

Comment: The pins of the chip can be used for input or output, but not at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

`DDR` controls the output enable on the driver stages.

`PORT` controls the input signal for the driver stages.

`PIN` is connected to the output of the comparator between the pin and the reference voltage.

In principle, it would be possible to merge `PORT` and `PIN` with a bunch of extra gates, but there is nothing to be gained from that.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong.

Comment: @LongPham Care to explain how you think he's wrong? I'm pretty sure he isn't.

Comment: umm please explain, isn't the content of port and pin always the same? why need 3 ? please explain where I get the concept wrong, anybody :( @marcelm

Comment: @SumantoDinar, the `PORT` register can be set even for input pins, to prepare the level that should be output when direction is changed (which you need for bidirectional protocols). For output pins, the `PIN` register should indeed read the same value.

Comment: It's technically / arguably mostly right but there is some confusing use of the words 'input' and 'output' here,  which would benefit from a picture of the data path from the datasheet.

Comment: @marcelm Oh, my thought is similar to vicantu.